# Is there a way to fully simulate clicking keyboard buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, keyboard-events

I have created an extension that manipulate a website inputs, in some inputs i need to simulate inserting value using keyboard buttons.

I tried to insert the value using `value` property but it doesn't work, i always need to insert the value with my hands clicking the buttons so the website can do some work which doesn't happen by inserting the value using `value`

i tried `dispatchEvent` with `newKeyboardEvent` and `keydown` but unfortunatley it doesn't work too which made me guess that it doesn't mimic the full function of keyboard button events

So is there any way to fully mimic pressing keyboard buttons?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.  it's a simple matter of protection against hacking

Comment: @MisterJojo so if the website input is linked to `change` event listener and i need to trigger that event with my extension  i have no way to achieve that??

Comment: It's still hacking and browsers won't make an exception for you